# Here is my query about the quarterly report, but it doesnt appear the all quarters, only 1 column appears

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, pivot

I have a two tables, one is the table Stations and the other one is table results, now I create a quarterly report from my tables. It shows only one column appeared on the quarterly reports.

```
SELECT tbl1.record_no
     , tbl1.station_id AS ID
     , tbl2.name AS `Station Name`
     , tbl1.param_code AS Parameter
     , (CASE WHEN QUARTER(date)=1 THEN IF(param_code="FC" || param_code="TC",  EXP( SUM( LOG(res_value) )/count(`res_value`)), AVG(`res_value`)) ELSE 0 END) AS `Q1`
     , (CASE WHEN QUARTER(date)=2 THEN IF(param_code="FC" || param_code="TC",  EXP( SUM( LOG(res_value) )/count(`res_value`)), AVG(`res_value`)) ELSE 0 END) AS `Q2`
     , (CASE WHEN QUARTER(date)=3 THEN IF(param_code="FC" || param_code="TC",  EXP( SUM( LOG(res_value) )/count(`res_value`)), AVG(`res_value`)) ELSE 0 END) AS `Q3`
     , (CASE WHEN QUARTER(date)=4 THEN IF(param_code="FC" || param_code="TC",  EXP( SUM( LOG(res_value) )/count(`res_value`)), AVG(`res_value`)) ELSE 0 END) AS `Q4`
  FROM tbl_wq_results AS tbl1
  LEFT 
  JOIN tbl_wq_station AS tbl2
    ON tbl1.station_id = tbl2.id
 WHERE station_cat = "Inland River Stations"
 GROUP 
    BY param_code
     , station_id  
 ORDER 
    BY `Station Name` ASC
```

This is the results of my Query appeared no values of Q1,Q2 even it has a value of my table tbl_wq_result.
[image: Here is the result]

this is my table named tbl_wq_result

[image: this my table tbl_wq_results]

Comment: I refer you again to my previous comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
            tbl1.station_id AS ID,
            tbl2.name AS `Station Name`,
            tbl1.param_code AS Parameter,
            (CASE WHEN param_code IN ("FC", "TC")
            THEN EXP(AVG(CASE WHEN QUARTER(date) = 1 THEN LOG(res_value) END))
            ELSE AVG(CASE WHEN QUARTER(date) = 1 THEN res_value END)
            END) as Q1,
            (CASE WHEN param_code IN ("FC", "TC")
            THEN EXP(AVG(CASE WHEN QUARTER(date) = 2 THEN LOG(res_value) END))
            ELSE AVG(CASE WHEN QUARTER(date) = 2 THEN res_value END)
            END) as Q2,
            (CASE WHEN param_code IN ("FC", "TC")
            THEN EXP(AVG(CASE WHEN QUARTER(date) = 3 THEN LOG(res_value) END))
            ELSE AVG(CASE WHEN QUARTER(date) = 3 THEN res_value END)
            END) as Q3,
            (CASE WHEN param_code IN ("FC", "TC")
            THEN EXP(AVG(CASE WHEN QUARTER(date) = 4 THEN LOG(res_value) END))
            ELSE AVG(CASE WHEN QUARTER(date) = 4 THEN res_value END)
            END) as Q4,
            YEAR(date) AS "YEAR"
            FROM tbl_wq_results AS tbl1
            LEFT JOIN tbl_wq_station AS tbl2
            ON tbl1.station_id=tbl2.id
            WHERE station_cat="'.$station_cat.'"
            GROUP BY param_code,station_id
            ORDER BY `Station Name` ASC
```

@GMB Thank you Sir, Problem Solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not a valid standard aggregation query, because the `select` and `group by` clauses are not consistent.

I suspect that the logic you want is:

```
SELECT 
    r.station_id AS ID,
    s.name AS `Station Name`,
    r.param_code AS Parameter,
    CASE WHEN r.param_code IN ('FC', 'TC')
        THEN EXP(SUM(CASE WHEN QUARTER(r.date) = 1 THEN LOG(res_value) END))
            / COUNT(CASE WHEN QUARTER(r.date) = 1 THEN r.res_value END))
        ELSE AVG(CASE WHN QUARTER(r.date) = 1 THEN res_value END) 
    END as Q1,
    CASE WHEN r.param_code IN ('FC', 'TC')
        THEN EXP(SUM(CASE WHEN QUARTER(r.date) = 2 THEN LOG(res_value) END))
            / COUNT(CASE WHEN QUARTER(r.date) = 2 THEN r.res_value END))
        ELSE AVG(CASE WHN QUARTER(r.date) = 2 THEN res_value END) 
    END as Q2,
    CASE WHEN r.param_code IN ('FC', 'TC')
        THEN EXP(SUM(CASE WHEN QUARTER(r.date) = 3 THEN LOG(res_value) END))
            / COUNT(CASE WHEN QUARTER(r.date) = 3 THEN r.res_value END))
        ELSE AVG(CASE WHN QUARTER(r.date) = 3 THEN res_value END) 
    END as Q3,
    CASE WHEN r.param_code IN ('FC', 'TC')
        THEN EXP(SUM(CASE WHEN QUARTER(r.date) = 4 THEN LOG(res_value) END))
            / COUNT(CASE WHEN QUARTER(r.date) = 4 THEN r.res_value END))
        ELSE AVG(CASE WHN QUARTER(r.date) = 4 THEN res_value END) 
    END as Q4
FROM tbl_wq_results AS r
INNER JOIN tbl_wq_station AS s ON r.station_id = s.id
WHERE station_cat = "Inland River Stations"
GROUP BY r.param_code, s.station_id  
ORDER BY `Station Name` ASC
```

The main point here is that only columns that appear in the `GROUP BY` clause are allowed to appear outside of the aggregate functions.

I also changed the aliases so they are more meaningful (and shorter), and (attempted to) alias all columns with the table they belong to.

Comment: Thank you Sir, but my concern is the formula of the parameter of Fecal coliform (FC) and Total Coliform was using a geomean and the among other parameters was using average, geomean formula was  EXP( SUM( LOG(res_value) )/count(`res_value`)), I'm looking forward to solve this problem and thank you for your bright idea.

Comment: @IvanCayabyab: the formulas are still there in the query, they are just organized differently, as explained in the answer. You should give this query a try.

Comment: I GOT Error
Static analysis:
227 errors were found during analysis. But I followed your concepts and try to fix it but it has a problem within the EXP(sum....

Answer (score 0):

---

It's perfectly works if all the parameters for the Water Quality was same by getting the Average. Total Coliform and Fecal coliform is using a geomean formula to get the average.

```
Select  tbl1.record_no, tbl1.station_id AS ID,tbl2.name AS `Station Name`, tbl1.param_code AS Parameter,
            AVG(CASE WHEN QUARTER(date)=1 THEN `res_value` ELSE  NULL END) AS `Q1`,
            AVG(CASE WHEN QUARTER(date)=2 THEN `res_value` ELSE  NULL END) AS `Q2`,
            AVG(CASE WHEN QUARTER(date)=3 THEN `res_value` ELSE  NULL END) AS `Q3`,
            AVG(CASE WHEN QUARTER(date)=4 THEN `res_value` ELSE  NULL END) AS `Q4`
            from tbl_wq_results AS tbl1
            left join tbl_wq_station AS tbl2
            on tbl1.station_id=tbl2.id
            where station_cat="Inland River Stations"
            group by param_code, station_id
```

ORDER BY `Station Name` ASC

and here is the result,
by using the geomean the correct output was the red one on the right side.

[image]